# Does the uniform distribution $U(1,n)$ have an equivalent Bernouli or beta distribution form?

Tags: distributions, beta-distribution, bernoulli-distribution

For a uniform distribution on the interval between $0$ and $1$, there is a $Beta(1,1)$ and Bernouli distribution $ Bernouli(1, 0.5)$ that can describe this. What parameter values for the Beta and Bernouli distribution that can describe the uniform distribution with interval $1$ and $n$?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: How does Bin(1,0.5) “describes” Unif(0,1)?

Answer (score 1):

Let's set aside the incompatibility of equivalence between a discrete distribution with a continuous one.

The standard definition of a beta distribution with density $f(x;\alpha,\beta)$ only has support on $[0,1]$. If you like you can define a "shifted" beta distribution that has support on $[\delta, 1 + \delta]$ for some $\delta$. Likewise, you could generalize the support to an interval wider than one. This isn't a "textbook" distribution, but it's perfectly valid (non-negative, total probability 1, etc). Wikipedia calls it a four-parameter beta distribution: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_distribution.

It has density

$$
f(y; \alpha, \beta, a, c) =\frac{ f(x; \alpha,\beta) }{c-a} = \frac{
\left(\frac{y-a}{c-a}\right)^{\alpha-1}
\left(\frac{c-y}{c-a}\right)^{\beta-1}}
{(c-a)B(\alpha,\beta)}
$$